# Is there any equivalent of in-place slice assignment for dict objects?

Tags: python, dictionary

In Python, the content of a `list` instance can be transformed nicely using a list comprehension—for example:

```
lst = [item for item in lst if item.startswith( '_' )]
```

Furthermore, if you want to change `lst` in place (so that any existing references to the old `lst` now see the updated content) then you can use the following slice-assignment idiom:

```
lst[:] = [item for item in lst if item.startswith( '_' )]
```

My question is: is there any equivalent to this for `dict` objects?   Sure, you can transform content using a dict comprehension—for example:

```
dct = { key:value for key,value in dct.items() if key.startswith( '_' ) }
```

but this is not an in-place change—the name `dct` gets re-bound to a new `dict` instance. Since `dct{:} = ...` is not legal syntax, the best I can come up with to change a `dict` in-place is:

```
tmp = { key:value for key,value in dct.items() if key.startswith( '_' ) }
dct.clear()
dct.update(tmp)
```

Any time I see a simple operation require three lines and a variable called `tmp`, I tend to think it's not very Pythonic.  Is there any slicker way to do this?

**edit**: I guess the filtering and the assignment are separate issues.  Really this question is about the assignment—I want to allow arbitrary transformations of the dict content, rather than necessarily just selective removal of some keys.

Comment: It can be done with a side-effect: `[dct.pop(key, None) for key in dct if not key.startswith('_')]`. But obviously that is not pythonic.

Comment: @ekhumoro  But then you get `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Comment: Yeah, I just spotted that. FWLIW: `[dct.pop(key, None) for key in list(dct) if not key.startswith('_')]`.

Comment: You can use `.update` but that will require creating an auxiliary dict. I generally consider in-place mutation an antipattern outside of limited, controlled areas

Comment: It is more that you should not depending on the object identity and sharing of references to base types than class instances where you can control their properties. In that it is better to hold a reference to an instance X that has a property A than hold a reference to the value of X.A and then depend on all your code updating that value in-place. When updating the attribute A of X is trivial: X.A = V.

Comment: @DanD. But now you've just moved the same problem somewhere else, since it is still possible to get a direct reference (unless `X.A` returns a deep copy). To truly avoid the problems of reference sharing, a better solution would be to make the `dict` an internal attribute of `X` and then provide public accessor methods for manipulating it.